# Guide to reviewing a scientific article

Tags: peer-review, undergraduate, physics

I'll be reviewing a scientific article soon and I've not done this before. It'll be reviewing a popular article on an astrophysical topic. Undergraduate level but I'm open to any level of guidance.

Is there a guide/textbook out there that describes how to write such a review in science?

Comment: If this is for a journal, they may have suggestions for reviewers.

Comment: treat the authors how you want to be treated as an author, the rest is objectivity, honesty, knowledge

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the other reviews where your review will appear. Then you can write yours using a similar style and level of technicality.

You can also ask for guidance from the person who asked you to write the review. That might be best done by offering particular paragraphs as examples of what you might say.

I doubt that there is a "guide" anywhere to help you with this, other than general guides to good writing.